# How to open excel in read and write mode?

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

Im opening the excel file from desktop and running a macro but everytime it shows an error stating that it cannot save as it is opened in read only mode

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EybOu.png)

Comment: A picture of your code is useless if you want someone to help debug it for you.  Please paste the code into the question.  Also, this does not look like VBScript.  Please show VBScript code if using VBScript, or update the tags if you aren't.

Comment: hi below is my code. It is executed from a vbs file from desktop but it displays an error stating that it cannot save as it is read only mode . Is there anything that i can do to get rid of it ? Thanks

Comment: @YowE3K, the person is using vba for excel, not vbs. He should remove vbs tag.

Comment: @MithileshIndurkar I've suggested a couple of times to the OP - in my comment above, and in a comment on the OP's (deleted) self-answer - that the vbscript tag is probably inappropriate, but the reply comes back as "It is executed from a vbs file", so I'm willing to give them the benefit of the doubt for now - but I would certainly be interested in seeing the VBS code as well as the VBA code shown in the image in the question and the (completely different) VBA code in the OP's self-answer.

Comment: Agree with you @YowE3K

Answer (score 0):

Can you check this and let me know if it works

```
Set Wb = Application.WorkBooks.Open(filePath, False, False) '3rd parameter is for opening the workbook in readonly mode 
'Your code
'
'Your code
'
Wb.Save ' OR ActiveWorkBook.Save
```

Answer (score 0):

7h parameter **True** value works.

see all parameters here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/office/vba/api/excel.workbooks.open

Good Luck!

Comment: I suspect you have a typo which is so distracting that it makes understanding your post quite hard. Also, adding some explanation would probably make the answer upvoteable.